# Sharepoint People View - add column with groups

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to customize the People View by adding a column with the group information. It seems I cannot do this from the List Settings as a Group collumn does not exist. So I guess I need to do some sort of custom development here.

What is recommended, Should I create a webpart and populate a grid manually from scracth. Or Is there an easy way to costumize the current list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a webpart and populated the grid manually using the Sharepoint Object Model API.